# Can `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions` be used from the Views?

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm rendering a dropdownlist that has an integer value and the `SelectListItem` value attribute only accepts a string thus the need for conversion. `.ToString()` function cannot be used.

```c#
@Html.DropdownList("ddl", Model.recordList.Select(
       q => new SelectListItem 
       { 
         Text = q.recordName, 
         Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert(q.recordId) 
       }
       , "choose one")

// recordId is an Integer
```

I get assembly reference error on runtime:

```
The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 
'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

There is a project reference to System.Data.Entity already and `@using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` in my View. I'm expecting this too as it doesn't appear in Intellisense. I can use from **Controllers** but **not in Views**.

Am I breaking any MVC rule here? Or probably have it misconfigured?

Comment: Why can't you use `ToString()`? `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` should be used only in Linq to Entities queries. `ToString()` is completely valid here.

Comment: @LukLed, I can't use `ToString()` because of this error: *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

Comment: @LukLed, it's a misconfiguration. Silly me... :)

Comment: `Model.recordList` shouldn't be passed to view as Linq To entities query. You should create view models, that don't consist of EF objects.

Comment: Thanks, LukLed. I understand what you mean. I'll revise my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's a misconfiguration.**

To resolve, I had to:

1) add it in the assembly references in the `Views/Web.config`.

```xml
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Data.Entity" />
            <add namespace="System.Data.Objects.SqlClient" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

2) Change the `Project > References > System.Data.Entity` property `Copy Local` = `True`. The assembly was not getting copied to the `bin` and thus identifies as `missing`.

Comment: I marked this as an answer because it was the solution to my problem. However, what I was doing was against the MVC concept as I was trying to load a database object from the Views. I revised my implementation and didn't require this anymore.